# How to select all element leaving first element?

Tags: jquery

I have jquery selector like

```
$("li a")
```

how can I modify it so it select all elements leaving first anchor tag ?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving" the first element?

Comment: I want all other elements using selector but I don't want to select first element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:gt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$("li a:gt(0)")
```

**Update: If you are interested in performance, the fastest by far is**

```
$("li a").slice(1)
```

about which the docs say:

> Because `:gt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using `:gt()` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   `$("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index)` instead.

Comment: which one will be faster gt or .not ? :)

Comment: I might say `gt` because it can do an one-off operation (cut off the first element), while `not` has to compare each element with the ones it needs to exclude. But the question is moot really -- both will be faster than you can tell.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: [Win7 x64] On FF 6.0.2, `gt` is faster by a small margin. On Chrome 14, `.not` is faster. In any case `:not` is the slowest. And `slice` totally obliterates everything else. Nice tool, interesting findings!

Comment: @Jon - I'm not really surprised by those results. `slice` should certainly be the fasted for the exact reasons stated in the jQuery docs. What always surprises me more is the sheer number of ways to do the same thing!

Answer (score 7):

[`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) is used to exclude elements and the pseudo-selector [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) is used to get the first one.
You can combine both to exclude first element like below:

```
$("li a").not(":first");
```

Or you can use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
$("li a:not(:first)");
```

**Update**

I have [profiled](http://jsperf.com/jq-gt-vs-first) three different methods and it appears that using the `.not` method along with `:first` selector is faster (tested in Chrome 14).

And another update, after reading @Jon's comment from the jQuery docs... using `.slice` is significantly faster than all jQuery methods! Here's a screenshot of the test results on Chrome 14:

[image]